# Gunicorn related error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

Below is my error log. I am running this command in the same folder as manage.py.... I have ensured that I am in a virtual environment and that Django is installed as a part of it. I don't understand why have issues with the following command -> gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 ctfWebsite.wsgi

```
    (djangodev) jordangethers@jordangethers-VirtualBox:\~/FSU-CTF-Website-main/FSUweb/x_ctfWebsite$         gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 ctfWebsite.wsgi
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9894\] \[INFO\] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9894\] \[INFO\] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9894)
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9894\] \[INFO\] Using worker: sync
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9895\] \[INFO\] Booting worker with pid: 9895
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9895\] \[ERROR\] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
worker.init_process()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
self.load_wsgi()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
self.callable = self.load()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 384, in import_app
mod = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return \_bootstrap.\_gcd_import(name\[level:\], package, level)
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1050, in \_gcd_import
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1027, in \_find_and_load
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1006, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib`your text`.\_bootstrap\>", line 688, in \_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap_external\>", line 883, in exec_module
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 241, in \_call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/jordangethers/FSU-CTF-Website-main/FSUweb/x_ctfWebsite/ctfWebsite/wsgi.py", line 12, in \<module\>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9895\] \[INFO\] Worker exiting (pid: 9895)
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9894\] \[INFO\] Shutting down: Master
\[2023-03-22 18:06:08 -0400\] \[9894\] \[INFO\] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
(djangodev) jordangethers@jordangethers-VirtualBox:\~/FSU-CTF-Website-main/FSUweb/x_ctfWebsite$ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in /home/jordangethers/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse\>=0.2.2 in /home/jordangethers/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from django) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref\<4,\>=3.5.2 in /home/jordangethers/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from django) (3.6.0)
(djangodev) jordangethers@jordangethers-VirtualBox:\~/FSU-CTF-Website-main/FSUweb/x_ctfWebsite$ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in /home/jordangethers/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref\<4,\>=3.5.2 in /home/jordangethers/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from django) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse\>=0.2.2 in /home/jordangethers/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from django) (0.4.3)
(djangodev) jordangethers@jordangethers-VirtualBox:\~/FSU-CTF-Website-main/FSUweb/x_ctfWebsite$
```

I tried adding the following to my ctfWebsite.wsgi file but they have not seemed to help. I also have tried various naming conventions and running the command in other directories but then of course it typically says ctfWebsite.wsgi not found or something along those lines.

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home/jordangethers/.virtualenvs/djangodev/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/home/jordangethers/FSU-CTF-Website-main/FSUweb/x_ctfWebsite/ctfWebsite')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ctfWebsite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Have you installed gunicorn inside the activated virtualenv?

Comment: I figured out the problem. For some reason my wsgi.py file could not resolve the django path. So I provided it manually by using sys.append('path') and importing django that way. I also had to do it for subsequent files but it eventually worked.